# Check html5 component visiblity inside webview using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap for developing my android application in my application there is a html5 page which is having some input text field and a submit button.

When user enters the values in text fields and click on submit it will call an ajax and for a good user experience I am showing a progress spinner from java script by making a div visible after clicking on submit button.

Inside my MainActivity java class i had overridden the onBackPressed method that will show a confirmation dialog before exit from app. Now What I want is when there is progress going on in html5 page means the div for progress image is visible I want to block the Back key to be pressed but my question is how can I identify the visiblity of that div inside the java class so that we can block it in java activity when the div is visible or else we allow user to exit by showing the confirmation dialog.

Is there anything inbuilt functionality in phone gap that we can use or we need to do something by own ?

Answer (score 0):

Well according to this [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) PhoneGap has an API to handle back-key events.
so you can use a private field in your java script code that will set a flag to visible or not (Boolean) and handle back-key event accordingly.

a pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var visible = false;
// Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
//
// At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.6.0.js has not.
// When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event `deviceready`.
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
    if(visible) {
     //wait
    } else {
      //finish
    }
}
function showDialog(){
     visible = true;
// your code
}
// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the offline event
//
function onOffline() {
}

</script>
```

Comment: I had tried that it is working fine on some device but on some device the application is getting crash while pressing the back button. So it will be better if we have something to handle it from native call .